# Maple basic: transform the maple results

Tags: maple

I was running `diff(abs(2*x + 5), x)`, maple gives me an answer of `2*abs(1, 2*x + 5)`

I actually dont know what that means. But I know the answer is `(4*x + 10)/abs(2*x + 5)`. How could I transform the answer from `2*abs(1, 2*x + 5)` to `(4*x + 10)/abs(2*x + 5)`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diff(abs(2*x + 5), x) assuming x::real;

                  /    5\
          2 signum|x + -|
                  \    2/

ans1 := normal(convert(%,abs));

                 2 x + 5
         ans1 := -------
                 |    5|
                 |x + -|
                 |    2| 

ans2 := (4*x + 10)/abs(2*x + 5);

                 4 x + 10 
         ans2 := ---------
                 |2 x + 5|

combine(normal(convert(ans1-ans2, signum)));

                 0
```

The meaning of `abs(1,x)` is described on the [Help page for the `abs` command](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=abs).